# Актуальность аплетов

Tags: java, java-8, applet

В книге Шилда "**Java 8 для начинающих**" пару раз разбирается создание *аплетов* разными средствами. Разве сейчас, эти *аплеты* не вытеснены `JavaScript`'ом? Другими словами, есть ли толк вникать в эту область, или же это стоит изучить для общего развития?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нет.

Насколько я знаю, современными браузерами апплеты не поддерживаются (без специального шаманства).

Answer (score 5):

С 2015-го года многие браузеры перестали поддерживать апплеты. С сентября 2017 Oracle объявили технологию устаревшей. Скорее всего, в 2019-м её окончательно уберут из Java.